# Display printed output while code is still running in C++ QT

Tags: c++, qt, tensorflow

I wrote a C++ tensorflow code which is working just as expected (using Cmake & make). But when executing the same code on QT Creator (using qmake), the code is not printing the output while it's still running. So we see no output till the execution is completed. Once its done executing, it then prints all the output at once.
I came across a [similar issue](https://github.com/IRkernel/IRkernel/issues/3) while looking for a solution. But it is for python. I appreciate any help.

Comment: This has way too little information to know what you're doing. Where do you want to see the output? I doubt that you need tensorflow etc. Minimize the code to 50 lines, to a single file. Yes, it can be done, and you should have done it first.

Comment: @kuba sorry for not being clear. `cout << "graph successfully imported."; cout << "Session successfully created."; cout << "graph successfully added to session.";` these are some lines I'm trying to print. added `cout << flush` before every cout statement. yet I'm getting only first 2 outputs/lines as expected and rest are getting printed all at once in the end(after the execution is completed). to be more clear, Its printing "graph imported and session created" then nothing till the execution is done, in the end printing all the remaining output -> "graph added to session... etc .. etc".

Comment: You still need to minimize it etc. What you're "clarifying" in reply to my suggestion doesn't add any information. It doesn't quite matter what text you're trying to output. What matters is whatever else you're doing that makes it somehow not work. If I write those same output statements and trigger them e.g. via a `QTimer`, they work just fine. So whatever you're doing wrong is up to you to demonstrate. All I can say is "works for me, sorry". You must help yourself by minimizing the problem. Please just do it.

Answer (score 1):

`std::cout` is buffered. Use `std::flush` to flush it or use `std::cerr` (which is unbuffered).

Comment: thanks! @Jesper Juhl its printing for the first 2 outputs but then its the same again for the rest. I added `cout << flush;` before every `cout` statement i the code.